# SWIFT String? does not have a member named 'element'

Tags: arrays, string, swift, label

I would like to know how can i fill my label from an Array

```
    func metaDataUpdated(metaData : NSString){
    var listItems: NSArray = [metaData.componentsSeparatedByString(";")]
    if ([listItems.count] > 0){
        println([listItems.objectAtIndex(0)])
       titleSong.text = [listItems.objectAtIndex(0)]
       }
    }
```

I don't really know how to convert an array to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot assign NSArray to NSString therefore you need to cast the value of this first index into a string

change this

```
        titleSong.text = [listItems.objectAtIndex(0)]
```

to

```
      titleSong.text = "\(listItems.objectAtIndex(0))"
```

or

```
      titleSong.text = listItems[0] as! String
```

and also change this line to `([listItems.count > 0])` to `(listItems.count > 0)`

your code will look like this:
**Note this not obj-c so remove all []**

```
func metaDataUpdated(metaData : NSString){
    var listItems: NSArray = metaData.componentsSeparatedByString(";")
    if (listItems.count > 0)
      {
        println(listItems.objectAtIndex(0))
       titleSong.text = listItems.objectAtIndex(0)  as! String
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct conversion to Swift:

```
func metaDataUpdated(metaData : String) {
    let listItems = metaData.componentsSeparatedByString(";")
    if listItems.count > 0 {
        print(listItems[0])
        titleSong.text = listItems[0]
    }
}
```

Nicer Swift:

```
func metaDataUpdated(metaData : String) {
    let listItems = metaData.componentsSeparatedByString(";")
    if let first = listItems.first {
        print(first)
        titleSong.text = first
    }
}
```

Even nicer Swift, without using `Foundation` and without the function needing to get every component separated by ";", but only the first one (recommended):

```
func metaDataUpdated(metaData : String) {
    if let index = metaData.characters.indexOf(";") {
        let first = metaData[metaData.startIndex ..< index]
        print(first)
        titleSong.text = first
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use Swift types and objects now: Array instead of NSArray, Dictionary instead of NSDictionary, etc.

```
func metaDataUpdated(metaData : NSString) {
    var listItems = metaData.componentsSeparatedByString(";")
    if listItems.count > 0 {
        print(listItems[0])
        titleSong.text = listItems[0]
    }
}
```

Here `componentsSeparatedByString` returns an array of strings: `[String]`. We then use simple index subscripting to retrieve its first value.

*Note: I suppose you were trying to adapt code from Objective-C because your example was ridden with `[]` everywhere...*

Comment: Actually `NSString` and `componentsSeparatedByString` are from `Foundation`…

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed. Thanks. I'll change the wording in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Put your to string item in `"\\()"`.

For instance:

```
titleSong.text = "\\([listItems.objectAtIndex(0)])"
```

Not sure you need the `[]` brackets though